# Location not detected when using fake position

Tags: android, android-location, android-maps-v2

I am implementing a navigation app, and I take the positions update like this:

```
private fun checkSettingsAndStartLocationUpdates() {

        val request: LocationSettingsRequest =
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest).build()
        val client: SettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(requireContext())
        val locationSettingsResponseTask: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> =
            client.checkLocationSettings(request)
        locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnSuccessListener {
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
        locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            if (e is ResolvableApiException) {
                try {
                    //e.startResolutionForResult(requireActivity(), 1001)
                    findNavController().navigate(
                        TutorFragmentDirections.toNoGpsSignalFragment(
                            locationRequest
                        )
                    )
                    val services = activity?.application as ApplicationServices?
                    viewModel.stopGeoTrigger(services = services, isGPS = false)
                } catch (ex: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    ex.printStackTrace()
                }
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

For testing purpose, I am using Lockito app, that helps me to simulate fake paths on map.
The problem is that the method above works with real tests or with Lockito runnung on a Samsung galaxy Note10 Lite, but it doesn't on Huawei p20 pro or Oppo (i don't know the model the tester is using), it goes inside `addOnFailureListener`.

Are there any things to change on the settings of the phone? Or is a device setting that can't be edited.

Comment: And what does `e.printStackTrace()` say for the `ResolvableApiException`?

Comment: it goes into the if (e is ResolvableApiException) and the exception is "6: RESOLUTION_REQUIRED"